# ionic angular controller statement block only runs once

Tags: angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I have "coupons.html" and when I click a coupon item I'm taken to "single-coupon.html" where my `SingleCouponCtrl` is called:

```
.controller('SingleCouponCtrl', function($scope, $state, userService) {
  console.log("Fire Up Single Coupon Controller");
})
```

So when I start on "coupons.html" and click an item I see

```
Fire Up Single Coupon Controller
```

In the console but if I hit the back button and click an item again I don't get a repeat of "Fire Up Single Coupon Controller". Shouldn't I be seeing that again since I'm recalling the page? If not, how can I get my controller to run again?

I've tried using `ng-init` and `$scope.init` but it only accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic cache a lot of things. I personnaly do the following on my routing JS ( `cache: false,` )

```
.state('camera',{
        url:"/camera",
        cache: false,
        controller:"CameraCtrl",
        templateUrl:'app/views/loading/index.html'
```

})